# A term for category where every loop of morphisms is an identity

Tags: category-theory, terminology

"A category where composition of every loop of morphisms is an identity."

Moreover, in the case I am thinking about, morphisms are bijective functions.

Is there a name for this concept?

Comment: Wouldn't such a category be a preorder?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine No, it could have several morphisms from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: OK, the object I am thinking about is a thin category. (Moreover it is a thin groupoid.) My question is satisfied now.

Comment: @Andreas: Really? I can certainly see that being the case if it's just a groupoid, but in the case where $hom(A,A)$ is a singleton for every $A$ (which sounds like what the first description is describing) that seems wrong...

Comment: @porton: It's also a topos with a non-empty initial object :D

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: I am totally ignorant in topoi theory, and so can't value the beautify of your comment

Comment: It's a silly use of the theorem that a cartesian closed category with a non-empty initial object is equivalent to the trivial category. It's me being a dork, in other words.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Yes, it can really happen. The smallest example would be a category with two objects, say $A$ and $B$, and four morphisms, namely the two identity morphisms and two other morphisms from $A$ to $B$.  The only composable pairs involve identity morphisms, so the composition operation is obvious.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Sorry, but WHAT can really happen?

Comment: An additional property of my particular category, is that there exist isomorphisms between every two objects. Is there a term for this?

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, of course.

Comment: @porton: Yes, with this additional property, it is indeed *equivalent* to the discrete category on one object: since any two objects are isomorphic, its skeleton has only one object, and the only endomorphism of this object must be the identity.

Comment: A category in which every endomorphism is an identity is called a [one-way category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/one-way%20category).