# Why "thin groupoids" are not ubiquitous?

Tags: notation, category-theory, terminology

[Google search for "thin groupoid"](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=q8yBVIjgMMyg8web5IDgAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22thin+groupoid%22) finds surprisingly few (namely 7) pages. But "thin groupoid" is a term to denote an important notation of a groupoid with every loop being the identity. I met it twice in my work. Why is it missing?

For example there are isomorphisms between filters and ideals. The groupoid (having just two objects) expressing this isomorphisms is thin, that is going from a filter to an ideal and then back to a filter is an identity.

Maybe an other term is used by mathematicians?

I draw a diagram with edges being isomorphisms between classes of objects and loops of isomorphisms are identities. Is there any term for this?

My question: What is a widespread notation related to this if any, or why there may be no such notation?

Two examples, from the theory of filters and theory of funcoids:

From [this online article](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/dual-filters.pdf) (an expanded above mentioned example about filters and ideals):

[image: filters]

From [this online article](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/funcoids-are-filters.pdf):

[image]

Note that all arrows in the above diagrams are isomorphisms (and moreover they are bijections, as they are isomorphisms of the category $\mathbf{Set}$).

See also [this my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843964/a-term-for-category-where-every-loop-of-morphisms-is-an-identity).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be describing a *setoid*.

Also, every such category is equivalent to a set (assuming the category is small); typically we only care about categories up to equivalence, so in such situations this notion doesn't give anything *new*.

However, as an aside, I think setoid is a better notion than set for many purposes, even outside the context of category theory. (e.g. when actually doing arithmetic, the ring of integers modulo some integer $m$ is usually treated in a way that resembles a setoid more than any other formalism)

I would use the term "setoid" to refer to any category equivalent to a setoid; I'm not sure if that matches up with common practice.

---

In your examples, however, you're not really asking about a kind of groupoid. You are specifically interested in things that aren't part of the groupoid structure, namely the actual identity of the morphisms.

The intent of caring about the actual identity of the morphisms seems to be for ZFC-style reasoning: you are using the identity of the morphisms to implicitly define a functor from your groupoid to your category of interest.

For example, one of your examples is essentially just a labelled diagram: the usual way to represent labelled diagrams in category theory is a functor $J \to \mathcal{C}$, where $J$ is an abstract category with the right shape.

As such, I think the natural way to express the structure you're interested in is via a functor whose domain is a "thin groupoid" and whose codomain is your category of interest.

As such, existing terminology for the structure you're interested in is quite unlikely to be form "groupoid satisfying properties".

Comment: I don't get how this is related with setoids. How to express my diagrams using setoids? I need particular isomorphisms not just the fact that two objects are isomorphic.

Comment: Isomorphisms are unique in your groupoid: for any groupoid and any two objects $X,Y$ of the groupoid, you have either $\hom(X,Y) \cong \hom(Y,X) \cong \hom(X,X)$ or $\hom(X,Y) \cong \hom(Y,X) \cong \varnothing$.

Comment: This is a standard fact about groupoids. Here's a short proof of part of it: if $f \in \hom(X,Y)$, then the function $f_* : \hom(X,X) \to \hom(X,Y)$  given by $f_*(g) = f \circ g$ is invertible, with inverse $(f_*)^{-1}(h) = f^{-1} \circ h$.

Comment: I yet don't understand you and don't see how to express this with setoids. When we switch from a thin groupoid to a setoid, the information about particular morphisms is lost (they are just replaced with a pair of objects), but the whole thing I need is information about what are particular morphisms, depicted as arrows in my diagrams.

Comment: @porton: I've had some time to think about it, and I can now put words to why I felt what you're trying to express seems so weird: you are specifically interested not just in the groupoid structure, but also in the relationship between that groupoid and some other category.

Answer (score 3):

As was explained by Hurkyl, thin groupoids are known as setoids. They appear in algebraic geometry. Whereas algebraic stacks are categories fibered in groupoids, schemes are [categories fibered in setoids](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04S9). For example, the fiber of $\mathbb{P}^n$ over $S$ is the category of $(\mathcal{L},s_0,\dotsc,s_n)$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle on $S$ and $s_0,\dotsc,s_n$ are global sections of $\mathcal{L}$ which generate $\mathcal{L}$. This is a setoid. Usually one replaces this (any?) setoid by its set of isomorphism classes.

Many other examples of setoids appeared in my research. The most basic one is the following: If $R,S$ are commutative rings, then the category of cocontinous tensor functors $\mathsf{Mod}(R) \to \mathsf{Mod}(S)$ is equivalent to the discrete category of ring homomorphisms $\hom(R,S)$. So in particular that category is a setoid. (The reason is basically that $R$ generates $\mathsf{Mod}(R)$ and that a cocontinous tensor functor is fixed on the unit object.)

Comment: But having two elements of setoids, I cannot restore particular morphism (such as $f\mapsto f\cap\Gamma$). It is not what I need

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: I need to describe a category. A category contains not only objects but also morphisms. As my category happens to be thin, there is a (not necessarily entire defined) function from pairs of objects into a morphism. Having a setoid we cannot define such a function. But I need this function. I need to be able to get the morphisms whenever a pair of objects is specified. Having only a setoid, I cannot do this.

Comment: So you downvote *my* answer because *you* haven't understood the definition of a setoid? Or you are asking something else without specifying it?

Comment: Setoid is a set with an equivalence relation on it. (And I know it long ago before I've read your answer.) I understand this. I downvote because switching from a groupoid to a setoid leads to information loss, and this makes it not an answer to my question.

Comment: A setoid can also be defined as a groupoid which is thin. See the stacks project for instance. It is an exercise to see that this is equivalent to give a set together with an equivalence relation. Please think before downvoting.

Comment: This your definition of setoids is not equivalent (however, it is equivalent up to equivalence of categories) to the standard definition of setoids, that is a set with an equivalence relation. Equivalence up to equivalence of categories is not enough for my purposes. I still think that I downvoted correctly,

Comment: Oh, I see: Some people use the word "setoid" differently. So my downvote was a mistake. I can't upvote it back now, sorry.

Comment: It is the same up to isomorphism of categories (not just equivalence!) and therefore "the same" in the best possible sense. If (X,R) is a setoid, the corresponding thin groupoid has object set X and morphisms x -> y are unique if they exist, and they exist if x R y. Conversely, if G is thin groupoid, let X be the object set, and define x R y to be "there is a morphism x -> y".